# How to run unix block command eg:if from perl

Tags: perl, unix, command-line

How to run a if block in unix from perl.
Eg:

```
location="/home/shon";
    if [[ -f $location/sample.txt ]]
    then
        echo "file found...."
    else
       echo "Error in getting file"
       exit 255
   fi
```

from perl.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is probably not the right place for your question.

Comment: yes i tried it.Please find the code below,
system("location='/home/shon'; if [[ -f $location/sample.txt ]] then echo 'file found....'; else echo 'Error in getting file'; exit 255 fi");
OP:syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Comment: Please [edit your queestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17377553) to format the code as code so it's easy to read. If you want a large group of strangers to read and understand your code, then it's only polite to make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: #! /usr/bin/perl
    my $location ="/home/shon/sample.txt";
    if (-f $location)
    {
      print "file found....";
    }
    else
    {
     print "Error in getting file";
    }

Comment: @rolindroy: That looks like an answer to the question. Why not post it as an answer, rather than a comment?

Comment: If you want to use `if` and `then` on the same line in shell then you need to separate them by a `;` as in `if [[ -f ... ]]; then ...`. Is that your problem?

Comment: @Dave I gave it as a readble code. but when posting, it comes in the single line... Please help me in it..

Comment: @PerlDuck :That holds good. it worked. But I was thinking if we can run a part of unix script as it is, in a .ksh file from perl..

Comment: _Re: I gave it as a readble code. but when posting, it comes in the single line_ Posts in comments cannot contain newline characters. They are always single-line and thus unreadable for non-trivial code. Furthermore, some languages (shell, python) _require_ newlines at certain places (or `;` instead). Posts in a question can be formatted just as in an editor (newlines, indentation, etc.), there's even a little toolbar for formatting. See [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Inserting newlines is as simple as hitting the ENTER key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, this code is simple to translate into perl. Assuming you have something more complex, you can spawn a shell to run it: put the shell code in a **quoted** heredoc so that perl does not substitute the shell variables.

```perl
system 'bash', '-c', <<'END_SHELL_CODE';
    location="/home/shon"
    if [[ -f $location/sample.txt ]]; then 
        echo "file found...." 
    else 
        echo "Error in getting file" 
        exit 255 
    fi
END_SHELL_CODE
```

Comment: Thanks @glenn_jackman : that is exactly what i looked for... Thanks for the response and if possible, could you Please breif the concept of spawnning a shell..

Comment: "spawn" just means to start a new process. Here, we're using perl's `system`  function to launch "bash" with some arguments.

Comment: Re "*put the shell code in a quoted heredoc so that perl does not substitute the shell variables.*", Could have used a single-quoted literal for that. What `<<'END_SHELL_CODE'` actually does is save you from having to escape `\ `.

Comment: @ikegami how to substitute a perl variable in the unix script as per your suggestion.
EG:
`#! /usr/bin/perl  
@cmds = @ARGV;  
chomp($schedule_id);  
system 'bash', '-c', <<'END_SHELL_CODE';  
@cmds  
END_SHELL_CODE  
print "shell executed:@cmds\n"; `

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
my $location ="/home/shon/sample.txt";
if (-f $location)
{
  print "file found....";
}
else
{
 print "Error in getting file";
}
```

Comment: My requirement is what ever the unix command passed to a wrapper_script.pl should execute the same.
the provided answer is the perl script equivalent to the unix script given in the questions. I need to run the unix script as the sample given above from perl.